# Validation Error in paypal checkout

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal

I am using PayPal checkout script on Angular5.

I am trying to split a string which contain the price and convert the result to float, but I get the following error:

```
{
"name": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
"details": [
    {
        "field": "transactions.amount",
        "issue": "Currency amount must be non-negative number, may optionally contain exactly 2 decimal places separated by '.', optional thousands separator ',', limited to 7 digits before the decimal point and currency which is a valid ISO Currency Code"
    }
],
"message": "Invalid request - see details",
"information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors",
"debug_id": "ea4b3e3713de"
}

request/</<@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:14680:39
```

Here is my paypal config:

```
let price = parseFloat(this.objRate.split("$")[1]);
let amount = 1;

let total = price * amount;
this.payPalConfig = {
  env: 'sandbox',
  client: {
    sandbox: '<key>',
    production: '<key>'
  },
  commit: true,
  payment: (data: any, actions: any) => {
    return actions.payment.create({
      payment: {
        transactions: [{
          amount: {
            currency: "USD",
            total: Number(total).toFixed(2)
          }
        }]
      }
    });
  },
  onAuthorize: (data: any, actions: any) => {
    return actions.payment.execute().then((payment: any) => {
      this.payPalSuccess = true;
    });
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try passing a hard coded decimal in the 'total' field?

Comment: What do you mean with "hard coded decimal"?

Comment: Instead of "total: Number(total).toFixed(2)" pass in "1.00"...

Comment: In fact when I defined `let price =1.55` it works. Why would this be?

Comment: Must be an issue with this so - parseFloat(this.objRate.split("$")[1]); Try debug the input

Comment: I debug that and return a number (`console.log(typeof price)`)

Comment: What's the value of the number though? `console.log(price)`

Comment: For example, this is the string `1 Month - $4.00` and that print `4`.

Comment: OK, so total should be 4, can you confirm with a `console.log(total)`. Also change `total: Number(total).toFixed(2)`  to `Number.parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);`

Comment: Total is not a string, and that is the argument for `parseFloat()`

Comment: what's the value output for `console.log(total)`

Comment: Basically the total you're sending to PayPal is not formatted correctly. To see what your sending you can debug locally or you could also check the request received in from PayPal - login to the sandbox and go to menu / transactions

Comment: Sorry, but I only see successful transactions on Summary page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve it by replacing the variable `total` in the configuration paypal checkout to another name like `total1`. Apparently there was a conflict between the key of configuration json and the variable of same name.